# "Pilgrims homelands'" or "Pilgrim's homelands"?

Tags: grammatical-number

The context for this is that the group of pilgrims all come from different places. So how would I refer to the [many]pilgrims [many]homelands?

I'm not sure where that apostrophe should go....

Thank you~

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The homelands of many pilgrims = the pilgrims' homelands.